# problem with the Majwick filter when processing data from the gyroscope

Tags: accelerometer, quaternions, gyroscope

When using the Majwick filter for a gyroscope-accelerometer, a problem is observed - the angle yaw (around the Z axis) smoothly changes by tens of degrees during rotation, if the rotation axis is located between the X and Y axes. What can this problem be associated with and how can the deviation of the angle be compensated yaw?

I used another filtrs ,like Mahony filter and everywhere the same problem

Comment: Few information to understand problem. Did you tried common implementation of Majwick?